# Use accelerometer values to control FPS on PC?

Tags: android, virtual, accelerometer, frame-rate

If I was running a FPS like counter-strike on my PC would it be possible to have the phone (connected to the PC via WiFi/Bluetooth) act as the mouse and control the character's looking direction? For example, the player stands up in front of his computer and points his phone up + down, and 360 degrees around him, and the character in the game follows the direction with its gun?

Answer (score 0):

Everything is possible.... Everything.

Assume you can write a socket class that would connect to your PC app. 
*I'm new to android so I don't know what it's got in it's native java*
- That would handle sending info to the desk... I don't think it would have to be significant amounts of data, but it would be a stream.

With that in place, I'd create a way to capture the movements of the PDA and push them to the DESK.

Okay now you've got the data from the PDA in the desk app's sphere.. 
*--it's best to do as much processing on the desk as you can.. More power.. --*
Record the values as you do things like turn around, and point the device up/down.. all the movements you can think of.

Finally, take the recorded values and see if you can "mimic" the actual moves in the game.

So; can it be done.  Sure.. easily?  That depends on your def of the word easy.